# How to search txt file using php

Tags: php, file, search

I am trying to search in a txt file using php. It is supposed to search the txt file and display results that it got from the file.

Here is my `php` code:

```
<?php
$file = 'my file.txt';
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
   echo "Found matches:\n";
   echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
}
else {
   echo "No matches found";
}
```

Comment: This `$file = 'my file.txt;` is throwing off Stack's syntax highlighting. Missing a quote.

Comment: Thanks @Fred -ii- But it does not work..

Comment: Maybe you forgot to actually read the contents from the file? [get_file_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: @trincot if you're going to post a possible duplicate, then why the answer? bit of a possible monopoly should that question be closed because of it

Comment: @trincot Plus, if other answers were to be submitted at a later time to possibly improve the question, then you'll have the entire show to yourself should it be closed by that duplicate. Sorry, but I don't think that marking it as a possible duplicate is fair for others who may want to submit more answers. I feel you should remove the duplicate.

Comment: I will remove the duplicate, but I found while I was writing the answer that that other issue had exactly the same code (variable names, echo text), as the Asker has used, ... except for the file contents. I find it ... well, peculiar. But I have no intention to take a monopoly, so I remove the duplicate call.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for your help...

Comment: @trincot Thanks, could you also delete that comment for it? Because the way that the Stack system works, it actually picks up on those keywords.

Comment: @ShiylohFisher you're welcome.

Comment: I have a question who is the downvoter?

Comment: I will counter it for you :)

Comment: Thank you!! for all your help @trincot

Comment: why did you change my edit after I fixed your spelling mistakes?

Comment: Oh i am sorry.. Edit again

Comment: It is not showing on mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use *$file* to read the file's contents into the *$contents* variable. You can use [get_file_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) for that. Also, it might be useful to turn this into a function, so you can re-use it for other files and search strings:

```
function searchInFile($file, $searchFor) {
    $contents = get_file_contents($file);
    if ($contents === false) return array(); // no file, no match
    $pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
    $pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
    preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches));
    return $matches[0];
}

$matches = searchInFile('my file.txt', 'concert');
if (count($matches)) {
    echo "Found matches:\n" . implode("\n", $matches);
} else {
    echo "No matches found";
}
```